# Why doesn't SimpleITK display image with imageJ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagej, itk, simpleitk

I am new in ITK. I wrote a small program to read image using sitk and display the image using imageJ.

```
import os
import SimpleITK as sitk

pathDicom = 'C://Users//clouds.png'
input = sitk.ReadImage(pathDicom)
sitk.Show( input , debugOn=True)
```

To link simpleITK to imageJ I set the environment variable. But I am getting following error for sitk.Show():

```
return _SimpleITK.Show(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK Show: C:\d\VS14-Win32-pkg\SimpleITK\Code\IO\src\sitkShow.cxx:580:
sitk::ERROR: Error in administrating child process: [Access is denied].
```

imageJ output is shown in the attached figure. Can someone tell what's the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What version of SimpleITK are you running.  It looks like it is not correctly finding the ImageJ executable.  The 2nd line of the output shows that it's trying to execute 'C:\Users\Harish\fiji-win64\Fiji.app'.  That's the Fiji directory, not the actual executable.

Can you try moving the Fiji.app directory to be directly inside your home directory?  So move it up a directory to get rid of fiji-win64 in the path.

By default it searches there, so maybe the fiji-win64 directory is messing it up.

The other thing you can try is the SITK_SHOW_COMMAND environment variable.  Set it to the full path of the ImageJ executable.  That will override the search for ImageJ.